# How does an LC network filter power?

Tags: capacitor, microcontroller

The ATMEGA datasheet suggests filtering the ADC reference voltage with an LC network, in other words VCC - L - AREF - C - GND. How does the inductor smooth the voltage better than just a capacitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At high frequency the impedance of the inductor increases and the impedance
of the capacitor decreases. For high frequency signals most of the signal voltage drop
is across the inductor.

The VCC (in a properly designed system) will have a very low impedance. By raising the impedance between VCC and AREF the capacitor will reduce more of any high frequency
noise that is on VCC.

On my boards I use a 10-20uH inductor and 0.1uF capacitors.

[corrected the first paragraph mistake that leon commented about]

Comment: For capacitors and inductors, it's impedance not resistance that change with frequency.

Comment: Correct. I used resistance in the first paragraph and impedance in the second. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It acts as a low-pass filter, removing high frequency noise much better than if just a capacitor was used.

Comment: They're both lowpass filters, but LC is second-order.